# Unmasking an element by assignment in a 2D numpy MaskedArray

Tags: python, numpy

With a 1 dimensional numpy MaskedArray I can assign to an element which unmasks the array:

```
In [183]: x = np.ma.MaskedArray(data=np.zeros((2),dtype=float),mask=True)

In [184]: x[0] = 9

In [185]: x
Out[185]:
masked_array(data = [9.0 --],
         mask = [False  True],
   fill_value = 1e+20)
```

With a 2 dimensional array, assigning to a single value does not unmask the array:

```
In [186]: x = np.ma.MaskedArray(data=np.zeros((2,2),dtype=float),mask=True)

In [187]: x[0][0] = 9

In [188]: x
Out[188]:
masked_array(data =
 [[-- --]
 [-- --]],
             mask =
 [[ True  True]
 [ True  True]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

If I assign to a slice, the slice gets unmasked

```
In [189]: x[0] = 9

In [190]: x
Out[190]:
masked_array(data =
 [[9.0 9.0]
 [-- --]],
             mask =
 [[False False]
 [ True  True]],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

How can I assign to a single value to unmask it?

Comment: Avoid `A[0][0]`, especially when assigning.  Sometimes it works, other times it does not.  You are supposed to use `A[0, 0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x[0, 0] = 9
```

It looks like when you execute `x[0][0] = 9`, NumPy decouples the `x[0]` temporary's mask from `x`'s mask, so the assignment only unmasks the `x[0]` temporary. The relevant code is in [`numpy/ma/core.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.9.1/numpy/ma/core.py#L3124):

```
            # Unshare the mask if necessary to avoid propagation
            if not self._isfield:
                self.unshare_mask()
                _mask = ndarray.__getattribute__(self, '_mask')
```

I don't know why it does that.

Comment: Thank you!  You're right, I should have been indexing correctly with [0,0].